# if statement switch

Tags: php

```
<?php

if ($_GET['user_id']) $content = $_GET['user_id'];
else $content = $_GET['content'];


switch($content) {

//The default page
default:
include_once('main.php');
break;

//The news related stuff
case 'news':
include_once('news.php');
break;

//Show the profile of a user
case 'user_id':
include_once('profile.php');
break;
 }
?>
```

`index.php?user_id=id` won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: define "doesn't work", and show how the variables are accessed within the included files.

Comment: without further clarification it will be impossible to offer better assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you intended this:

```
if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) $content = 'user_id';
```

Instead of:

```
if ($_GET['user_id']) $content = $_GET['user_id'];
else $content = $_GET['content'];
```

Then the `switch` would execute the `user_id` case and include `profile.php`.

Comment: You should have said that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

the `default` case needs to be the last one.

```
switch($content) {
    //The news related stuff
    case 'news':
        include_once('news.php');
    break;

    //Show the profile of a user
    case 'user_id':
        include_once('profile.php');
    break;

    //The default page
    default:
        include_once('main.php');
    break;
}
```

Plus, you said that this doesn't work: `index.php?user_id=id`

The `$content` variable is being populated by the value of `user_id` in the _GET string, therefore if you wanted to see something other than the default page, you'd have to do one of these:

```
index.php?user_id=news
index.php?user_id=user_id
```

This probably isn't how you want it to behave, but given your code, this is what it's doing...

Comment: You haven't specified what you mean when you say that it "dont work". What does it do, and how does that differ from what you expect it to do? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The default case doesn’t need to be the last one.

Comment: well, if you want the other cases to fire, then it needs to be after them.

Comment: hmm ok, I just looked it up and apparently you're right: it's not a technical problem, though it is a readability problem IMHO.